# R: Remove words systematically from corpus after processing topic model

Tags: r, topic-modeling, topicmodels

I am doing topic modeling with the [topicmodels](/questions/tagged/topicmodels)-package and a corpus consisting of three documents.

```
model <- LDA(dat_dtm, method = "VEM", k = 3, control = list(alpha = 0.1))
```

Output:

```
A LDA_VEM topic model with 3 topics.
```

After that, I use the [terms](/questions/tagged/terms)-function to obtain the top 5 words of each model.

```
terms(model, 5)
```

Outuput with made up words:

| topic 1 | topic 2 | topic 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| strong | poor | class |
| wealth | struggle | middle |
| money | homeless | money |
| power | money | sufficient |
| rich | wealth | wealth |

As you can see, the words "money" and "wealth" appear in each topic, but they are not really meaningful for my analysis. So I thought it might be a good idea to remove these words from the whole corpora and conduct a new topic model without them. I tried to do this automatically by telling R that it should observe the top 20 words for each topic and remove all words from the corpora which are in each topic under the top 20. However, I only generated errors because I am not really familiar with the [topicmodels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/topicmodels)-package. Obviously, you can just add these words to the stop word list manually, but maybe there is a more professional way to do it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to make a vector object of the top 20 words and add it to your stop word list.

You can use `tidyverse` to specify these words for each topic.

```
library(tidyverse)

remove_words <- model %>% 
  tidy(matrix = "beta") %>% 
  group_by(topic) %>%
  slice_max(beta, n = 20) %>% 
  pull(term)
```

Now you have a vector object called `remove_words`, which should be added into your stop word list before conducting a new topic model.

Hope this helps!